# create a script to return the date of the most recent date file and append it to a file name

Tags: powershell, vbscript

My goal is to centralize information about when the last user backup was completed.

On my network, I have backups run to these locations:

```
\\server\backup\user1
\\server\backup\user2
\\server\backup\user3
```

and so on.

My goal is to run a script that will check each of those folders and return information on the date of newest file in each folder appended to the name of the user.

The output would look something like this:

```
user1-2-17-12-1457
user2-1-18-12-1312
user3-2-6-12-0857
```

where 2-17-12-1457 represents date and time of newest file on \server\backup\user1

This script will be run on a Windows 2008 SBS machine, so whatever tools available to me there will be available.  I run relatively basic batch files, but I'm open to whatever gets the job done.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want that date format?  user1-12-02-17-1457 would make them sort in chronogical order by filename.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below should do the trick. Replace the two instances of "lastwritetime" with "creationtime" if you're worried about the file creation date instead. Also would need to tweak the final .tostring() format in case I didn't glean exactly the format of the timestamp you're desiring.

```
$directories = get-childitem "\\server\backup" | where-object { $_.psiscontainer } 

foreach ($dir in $directories) { 
  get-childitem $dir | sort-object lastwritetime | select-object -last 1 | foreach-object { $dir.name + $_.lastwritetime.tostring("-MM-dd-yy-hhmm") }
}
```

This should output something like this:

```
copy-04-13-11-0213
Fiddler2-10-21-10-0120
My Received Files-11-14-11-0233
net-09-03-10-1023
OneNote Notebooks-02-07-12-0306
SQL Server Management Studio-03-17-11-1056
Visual Studio 2005-03-17-11-1056
Visual Studio 2008-03-17-11-1048
Visual Studio 2010-03-22-11-0650
windowspowershell-11-07-11-0303
```

EDIT: 
Per comments.. Adding logging to a file (which itself is timestamped with current date), and using fullpath to ensure we don't rely on relative paths.

```
$directories = get-childitem "\\server\backup" | where-object { $_.psiscontainer } 
$outFile = "C:\recentfiles" + (get-date).toString("-MM-dd-yy") + ".txt"

foreach ($dir in $directories) { 
  get-childitem $dir.Fullname | sort-object lastwritetime | select-object -last 1 | foreach-object { $dir.name + $_.lastwritetime.tostring("-MM-dd-yy-hhmm") } | out-file $outFile -append
}
```

Comment: this is awesome.  One thing I'd like to do differently is the output of the data.  My plan for this script is to run in nightly on the folders where my users back up so each morning, I can see the status of backups.  Could we make the script do this?

Comment: I don't follow, what are you looking to do differently? Output to file rather than to console? If that's all, it should be easy to redirect the output, or pipe to out-file -append

Comment: you do follow.  I'd like to output to file.  As I researched, out-file is exactly what I want.  But honestly, this is the first time I've ever looked at powershell scripting and could use some guidance.

Comment: actually, if we could use the new-item cmdlet to create a file with the output of the script, that would be ideal.  I'm going to try it, but again I'm a newbie with powershell

Comment: in your code: $directories = get-childitem "\\server\backup" | where-object { $_.psiscontainer }    this is greatin that this code will dynamically pick up an subfolder of \\server\backup - but the problem from my tests is that the PS1 file has to be located in \\server\backup or else the script doesn't work properly.  Is there a way to edit this line so that you can store the PS1 file in a folder like c:\powershell and run the script against \\server\backup?  Thanks

Comment: Check out my edit. I was (unintentionally) relying on relative paths when I did get-childitem $dir. I've modified that bit to make sure this will work regardless of what the current working directory is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that searches all of the files recursively in the profile to find the most recently written one. It then parses that data info into a string which is concatenated to the initial folder's name.

```
$Folders = @(
        "\\server\backup\user1",
        "\\server\backup\user2",
        "\\server\backup\user3"
)

$Folders | % {
    $Directory = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_
    $AllFiles = Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse
    $NewestDate = ($AllFiles | Sort-Object -property LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format "-M-d-yy-HHmm"
    $NewFileName = "$($Directory.Name)$NewestDate"
    $NewFileName

}
```

Comment: this is also great.  Is there a way to output the data to filenames instead of to the screen?

Comment: I was able to combine both scripts and accomplish what I needed.  I used @riknik 's lanaguage to dynamically pull the folder names from the destination directory.  Then I used Geoff's script which (in my eyes) allowed me to create a new-file cmdlet.  However, I have one problem - using riknik's script, the script only runs properly if the PS1 file is in the same folder as the folders it is testing.  More precisely, if I set the containing folder to c:\apps, but the PS1 file is located in c:\powershell, the script will not run properly.  But if I put the PS1 in c:\apps, it runs normally.

Comment: Here is my current script:    $Folders = get-childitem "c:\apps" | where-object { $_.psiscontainer } 


$Folders | % {
    $Directory = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_
    $AllFiles = Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse
    $NewestDate = ($AllFiles | Sort-Object -property LastWriteTime -Descending)[0].LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format "-M-d-yy-HHmm"
    $NewFileName = "$($Directory.Name)$NewestDate"
    new-item c:\status\$NewFileName -type file -force

}